# Php script to loop list of urls and save as PDFs?

Tags: html, scripting

I was wondering if it was possible and what exactly I would need to loop through a list of url links and save those pages as pdfs. I would like to create a script that could do this but not sure how realistic it is.

Example:

www.site1.com
 - save pdf locally site1.pdf
www.site2.com
 - save pdf locally site2.pdf

Comment: Is the PDF just going to be a static image of the site?

Answer (score 0):

It is realistic, although it needs a bit coding, as saving HTML pages as PDF files is not that simple.

There are libraries like FPDF or mPDF for PHP that can convert a HTML doc into a valid pdf, but it will not take a 'screenshot' of the page, but rather build it from the HTML tags and the CSS. They even allow changing the CSS file to your custom one.
(If you want to take a screenshot there is always PHP's `imagegrabscreen()`, but it will only work on a Windows server.)

You will just have to fetch the dom from your url:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://site1.com');
```

Convert it to a pdf with one of the mentioned libraries, and save it as a file:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

See:
http://fpdf.org

http://mpdf1.com

(I personally prefer mPDF - it is based on FPDF and has a nice and easy API.)